# Javascript Regular Expression with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, regex, nginx-njs

I am using Nginx njs module for some url modifications.

My use case is to return the redirection uri for the given uri.

URI's will be as follows:

```
/books
/books/economic-genious
/books/flight-mechanics
```

My regular expression to match the above URI's as follows -

`/books/(.*)|/books$`

First part of expression `/books/(.*)`  is to match below URI's:

```
/books/economic-genious
/books/flight-mechanics
```

Second part of expression `/books$`  is to match below URI's:

```
/books
```

My destination is configured as follows: `/ebooks/$1`. So that the above URI's will be converted to:

```
/ebooks
/ebooks/economic-genious
/ebooks/flight-mechanics
```

Javascript code:

```
function getMappedURI(uri) {
    var exp = new RegExp('/books/(.*)|/books$');
    var destUri = '/ebooks/$1';
    var redirectUri = uri.replace(exp, destUri);
    return redirectUri;
}
```

Above code is working fine for the below URI's:

```
/books/economic-genious
/books/flight-mechanics
```

But for the URI `/books`, it should return `/ebooks/`. But it is appending some non printable special character at the end of `/ebooks/`.

I think it is trying to replace `$1` with some special character.

How to avoid adding of special character at the end ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this regex:  `\/books(\/(.*))?$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DqnIiq/16) here...

code:

```
function getMappedURI(uri) {
    var exp = new RegExp('\/books(\/(.*))?$');
    var destUri = '/ebooks$1';
    var redirectUri = uri.replace(exp, destUri);
    return redirectUri;
}
```

Comment: It is transforming "books123" to "ebooks/123". It is not a match.

Comment: u not said charackter after book.. i will update regex

Comment: It should not append 123. It should not be a match

Comment: do u want to ignore it?

Comment: Yes, I want to ignore it.

Comment: hope this help u

Answer (score 1):

The OR `|` operator only works in parens. So you should make the match to `(/books/(.*)|/books$)` and I don't think the `$` word match because, for anything to be matched It should be in parens, too, making the new match URL:  `(/books/(.*)|/books)`. You'll then have to use $2 instead of $1 as substitute instead.

```
function getMappedURI(uri) {
    var exp = new RegExp('(/books/(.*)|/books)');
    var destUri = '/ebooks/$2';
    var redirectUri = uri.replace(exp, destUri);
    return redirectUri;
}
```

But, if you want to want everything from `/books/foo` to `/ebooks/foo`, use this instead: `/books/(.*)` with $1 as substitute.

```
function getMappedURI(uri) {
    var exp = new RegExp('/books/(.*)');
    var destUri = '/ebooks/$1';
    var redirectUri = uri.replace(exp, destUri);
    return redirectUri;
}
```

Comment: Tried with ```var exp = new RegExp('(/books/(.*)|/books)');``` Still it is appending special character at the end. Because of the additional special character redirection is failing.

Comment: Which special character is it appending?

Comment: Non-printable special character . Character code is '0x07'.